# Parsing value in array Json to php on my query

Tags: php, arrays, json, parsing

I have JSON file format like this:

```
[{
    "link": "http://urlkemanaaja-1",
    "datacontent": ["kema aja kita bersama  ", ", bersama kita berdua  ", "melewati batas", " ", "\u00a0"],
    "title": "Berharap engkau, kembali"
},
{
    "link": "http://urlkemanaaja-2",
    "datacontent": [" Marilah kemari  ", "hai kawan\u00a0juncto ", "tim penasihat hukumnya dalam sidang yang akan digelar pada Senin pekan depan."],
    "title": "Berharap engkau pergi darisini"
}]
```

How can I extract data to my php program?

And this is my code I tried and not work, because not all datacontent insert to my sql, to many comma, this my code on php:

```
include "db/cfg.php";
$json = file_get_content('http://anuku.com/details.json');
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
foreach ($obj as $track) { 
    $link = $track['link'];
    for($a=0; $a < count($track['datacontent']); $a++) {
        $content = $track['datacontent'][$a];
    } 
    echo  $sqlupdate = "UPDATE pay_tbl_news SET content= '$content' WHERE link = '$link'".'<br><br>';
}
```

What is wrong with my code? What i need is I want to capture all datacontent and link for my sql query.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you data content is overriding in for each. so will end up with only last part data content.

```
foreach ($obj as $track) { 
$link = $track['link'];
for($a=0; $a < count($track['datacontent']); $a++)
{
   $content = $track['datacontent'][$a]; // overwrite 
}
```

if you want save all data content you can save it as ',' separated you can use implode like below

```
foreach($obj as $track) 
{ 
   $link = $track['link'];
   $content = implode(',',$track['datacontent']);
}
```

or you can save data content in json format itself. like

```
foreach($obj as $track) 
{ 
   $link = $track['link'];
   $content = json_encode($track['datacontent']);
}
```

Comment: Hi dude it work many thanks ... this my i need  $content = implode(',',$track['datacontent']);